# Latest date from a date list >180 days in past from a given date in same list

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, frequency

I have a "Appeared date" column A and next to it i have a ">180" date column B. There is also "CONCAT" column C and a "ATTR" column D.

What i want to do is find out the latest date 180 or more from past, and write it in ">180" column, for each date in "Appeared Date" column,  where the Concat column values are same.

The Date in >180 column should be more than 180 days from "Appeared date" column in the past, **but should also be an earliest date found only from the "Appeared date" column**.

Based on this i would like to check if a particular product had "ATTR" = 'NEW' >180 earlier also i.e. was it launched 180 days or more ago and appearing again recently?

- Is there an excel formula which can get the nearest dates (>180) picked from the Appeared date and show it in the ">180" column?
- Will it involve a mix of SMALL(), FREQUENCY(), MATCH(), INDEX() etc?
- Or a VBA procedure is required?

[image]

Comment: How many records do you have? Reason I ask is that there are many ways to solve this, but generally the easiest methods are the less efficient, to the point that they might become unworkable on large data sets.

Comment: You can do this with formulas as per my answer below, but some well-written VBA or perhaps some PowerQuery or DAX (if you have PowerPivot) will possibly be more efficient and easier to understand.

Comment: @Jeffreyweir, datasets range from minimum 3k to 50k records.

Comment: The records could range from 3k to 50k in a single dataset. So need a very fast solution. Thought of ADO, but it means picking each row and checking against the others. Same went with using excel filters for processing. Probably a single ADO query could suffice, but don't know how to write such a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this efficiently with formulas, you can use something called Range Slicing to reduce the size of the arrays to be processed, by efficiently truncating them so that they contain just the subset of those 3,000 to 50,000 rows that could possibly hold the correct answer, and THEN doing the actual equality check. (As apposed to your MAX/Array approach, which does computationally expensive array operations on  *all* the rows, even though *most* of the rows have no relationship with the current row that you seek an answer for).

Here's my approach. First, here's my table layout:
[image]

...and here's my formulas:

```
180: =[@Appeared]-180
Start: =MATCH([@CONCAT],[CONCAT],0)
End: =MATCH([@CONCAT],[CONCAT],1)
LastRow: =MATCH(1,--(OFFSET([Appeared],[@Start],,[@End]-[@Start])>[@180]),0)+[@Start]-1
LastItem: =INDEX([Appeared],[@LastRow])
LastDate > 180: =IF([@Appeared]-[@LastItem]>180,[@LastItem],"")
Days: =IFERROR([@Appeared]-[@[LastDate > 180]],"")
```

Even with this small data set, my approach is around twice as fast as your MAX approach. And as the size of the data grows, your approach is going to get exponentially slower, as more and more processing power is wasted on crunching rows that can't possibly contain the answer. Whereas mine will get slower in a linear fashion. We're probably talking a difference of minutes, or perhaps even an hour or so at the extremes.

Note that while you could do my approach with a single mega-formula, you would be wise not to: it won't be anywhere near as efficient. splitting your mega-formulas into separate cells is a good idea in any case because it may help speed up calculation due to something called multithreading. Here’s what Diego Oppenheimer, a former program manager for Microsoft Excel, had to say on the subject back in 2005 :

*Multithreading enables Excel to spot formulas that can be calculated concurrently, and then run those formulas on multiple processors simultaneously. The net effect is that a given spreadsheet finishes calculating in less time, improving Excel’s overall calculation performance. Excel can take advantage of as many processors (or cores, which to Excel appear as processors) as there are on a machine—when Excel loads a workbook, it asks the operating system how many processors are available, and it creates a thread for each processor. In general, the more processors, the better the performance improvement.*

Diego went on to outline how spreadsheet design has a direct impact on any performance increase:

*A spreadsheet that has a lot of completely independent calculations should see enormous benefit. People who care about performance can tweak their spreadsheets to take advantage of this capability.*

The bottom line: Splitting formulas into separate cells increases the chances of calculating formulas in parallel, as further outlined by Excel MVP and calculation expert Charles Williams at the following links:

[Decision Models: Excel Calculation Process](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm#MultiThread)

[Excel 2010 Performance: Performance and Limit Improvements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514%28v=office.14%29.aspx#MultithreadedCalculation)

Comment: This is excellent info. Indeed it reduces overhead memory. I am currently looking for an ADO query solution with VBA as the data is huge and there are other analysis also that need to be done on this data. I shall raise a separate post for it soon. Thanks Jeff. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer. Earlier i was using the MIN function, though incorrectly, as the dates in the array formula (when you select and hit F9 key) were coming in descending order. So i finally used the MAX function to find the earliest date which was more than 180 in the past.

```
=IF(MAX(IF(--(A2-$A$2:$A$33>=180)*(--(C2=$C$2:$C$33))*(--
($D$2:$D$33="NEW")),$A$2:$A$33))=0,"",MAX(IF(--(A2-$A$2:$A$33>=180)*(--
(C2=$C$2:$C$33))*(--($D$2:$D$33="NEW")),$A$2:$A$33)))
```

Check the revised [Sample.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByraEKowSDpWdUtPbkJlei1JNjQ/view?usp=sharing) which is self-explanatory. I have added the Attr='NEW' criteria in the formula for the final workaround, to find if there were any new items that came 180 days or earlier.

Though still an ADO query alternative may be required to process the large amounts of data.

Comment: This formula essentially calculates the same answer twice, thanks to the IF statement around the outside. That is a very inefficient way to hide items that would otherwise show "1900-01-00". Better to just keep the last part of the formula, and use another column to check if the answer was NOT "1900-01-00".  And in fact that last part can be simplified further to just =MAX(([@[Appeared date]]-[Appeared date]>=180)*([@CONCAT]=$C$2:$C$33)*[Appeared date]) if you leave out the Attr='NEW' bit. But even then, it is going to be far less efficient than the general form I take with my original answer.

Comment: Note that if we leave out the Attr='NEW' bit for simplicity, your formula does something different than your stated logic. Here is a description of what it is doing: "For each item in the Concat column, retrieve the LATEST previous sale date of the same item if that sale occurred MORE than 180 days ago." (Whereas your original question asked for the EARLIEST previous sale date more than 180 days ago)

Comment: "For each item in the Concat column, retrieve the LATEST previous sale date of the same item if that sale occurred MORE than 180 days ago." Yes thats TRUE. Sorry for incorrect wording issue. I wanted to do away with helper columns as i am already dealing with more than 40 columns.

Comment: Doing away with helper columns will DRAMATICALLY decrease the formula efficiency...to the point that your approach with MAX might become completely unworkable. Whereas my original approach (suitably amended to handle the reworked wording) will likely be many, many times faster as it drastically reduces the size of the arrays through something called "Range Slicing"

Comment: Can you please edit your original post to reflect the revised logic statement in your last comment, as well as showing a revised image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Also note that VBA will be much more efficient that using a formula in this case. I doubt that an ADO solution is possible or efficient. I'll amend my original formula-based answer for you, but I don't have time right now to write a VBA approach. But sorting the arrays before processing them will be the key to fast execution, because then you can quit looking for further matches once you've worked backwards from the current item's date and found the first previous item in the list that is more than 180 days old.